# How Galera Cluster guarantees consistency?

Tags: mariadb, percona, galera, percona-xtradb-cluster

I'm searching for a high-available SQL solution! One of the articles that I read was about "virtually synchronized" in Galera Cluster: https://www.percona.com/blog/2012/11/20/understanding-multi-node-writing-conflict-metrics-in-percona-xtradb-cluster-and-galera/

He says

> When the writeset is actually applied on a given node, any locking 
>   conflicts it detects with open (not-yet-committed) transactions on
>   that     node cause that open transaction to get rolled back.

and

> Writesets being applied by replication threads always win

What will happen if the WriteSet conflicts with a committed transaction?

He also says:

> Writesets are then “certified” on every node (in order).

How does Galera Cluster make WriteSets ordered over a cluster? Is there any hidden master node who make WriteSets ordered; something like Zookeeper? or what?

Answer (score 1):

This is for the second question (about how Galera orders the writesets).

Galera implements **Extended Virtual Synchrony (EVS)** based on the Totem protocol.  The Totem protocol implements a form of token passing, where only the node with the token is allowed to send out new requests (as I understand it). So the writes are ordered since only one node at a time has the token.

For the academic background, you can look at these:

[The Totem Single-Ring Ordering and Membership Protocol](http://www.cs.jhu.edu/~yairamir/tocs.ps)

[The database state machine and group communication issues](http://infoscience.epfl.ch/record/32566)

Answer (score 0):

(This Answer does not *directly* tackle your Question, but it may give you confidence that Galera is 'good'.)

In Galera (PXC, etc), there are two general times when a transaction can fail.

1. On the node where the transaction is being run, the actions are compared to what is currently running on the *same* node.  If there is a conflict, either one of the transactions is stalled (think `innodb_lock_wait_timeout`) or is deadlocked (and rolled back).
2. At `COMMIT` time, info is sent to all the other nodes; they check your transaction against anything on the node or pending (in gcache).  If there is a conflict, a message is sent back saying that there would be trouble.  So, the originating node has the `COMMIT` fail.  For this reason, you must check for errors even on the `COMMIT` statement.

As with single-node systems, a deadlock is *usually* resolved by replaying the entire transaction.

In the case of `autocommit`, there is a small, configurable, number of retries, after which the statement will fail.  So, again, check for errors.  However, since a retry has already been tried, you may want to abort the program.

Currently (in my opinion) Galera, with at least 3 nodes in at least 3 different physical locations, is the best available HA solution for MySQL.  It can effectively survive any single-point-of-failure.  (Group Replication / InnoDB Cluster, from Oracle, is coming soon, and is very promising.)

One thing to note is that the "critical read" problem has a solution in Galera, but you have to take action.  See `wsrep_sync_wait`.  (As of this writing, InnoDB Cluster has no solution.)

See http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/galera  for tips (some of which are included above) on coding differences when moving to PXC/Galera.